# Error when including bibliography on TexMaker

Tags: bibliographies, texmaker, overleaf

I started to write my LaTex document on Overfleaf and now I want continue to write it on local using TexMaker.

However, when I build the document (using Quickbuild with PdfLatex + biblatex + pdflatex (x2) + view pdf) I get this error:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/Debian) 
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux 
The style file: biblatex.bst 
A level-1 auxiliary file: Chapters/Introduction.aux 
A level-1 auxiliary file: Chapters/Background.aux 
A level-1 auxiliary file: Chapters/Motivation.aux 
A level-1 auxiliary file: Chapters/Approach.aux 
A level-1 auxiliary file: Chapters/Implementation.aux 
A level-1 auxiliary file: Chapters/Evaluation.aux 
A level-1 auxiliary file: Chapters/Conclusions.aux 
Database file #1: main-blx.bib 
Database file #2: bibliography.bib 
Repeated entry---line 102 of file bibliography.bib : @inproceedings{yianilos1993data : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry 
Repeated entry---line 468 of file bibliography.bib : @article{oliva2001modeling : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry  
Repeated entry---line 694 of file bibliography.bib : @inproceedings{torii201524 : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry 
Repeated entry---line 713 of file bibliography.bib : @inproceedings{philbin2007object : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry Repeated entry---line 969 of file bibliography.bib : @article{cambazoglu2012cache : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry Repeated entry---line 1124 of file bibliography.bib : @book{shakhnarovich2006nearest : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry Repeated entry---line 1202 of file bibliography.bib : @misc{phash : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry Repeated entry---line 1214 of file bibliography.bib : @inproceedings{douze2009evaluation : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry Repeated entry---line 1223 of file bibliography.bib : @article{oliva2001modeling : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry Repeated entry---line 1631 of file bibliography.bib : @article{abbasifard2014survey : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry Repeated entry---line 1663 of file bibliography.bib : @inproceedings{delhumeau2013revisiting : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry Repeated entry---line 1699 of file bibliography.bib : @inproceedings{zheng2009tour : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry Repeated entry---line 1732 of file bibliography.bib : @inproceedings{cao2014fast : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry Repeated entry---line 1741 of file bibliography.bib : @inproceedings{zheng2009tour : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry Repeated entry---line 2451 of file bibliography.bib : @inproceedings{perd2009efficient : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry Repeated entry---line 2532 of file bibliography.bib : @article{jegou2012aggregating : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry Repeated entry---line 2576 of file bibliography.bib : @article{wang2014trinary : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry Repeated entry---line 2700 of file bibliography.bib : @article{zhang2007local : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry Repeated entry---line 2711 of file bibliography.bib : @inproceedings{logan2001music : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry Repeated entry---line 2914 of file bibliography.bib : @incollection{bay2006surf : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "sect:objectInstanceRecognition" Biblatex version: 3.3 (There were 20 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

Notice that the error doesn't show with the default quickbuild (and not including the bibliography. How do I solve it?

This is the `main.tex` file:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Masters/Doctoral Thesis 
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.4 (22/11/16)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Version 2.x major modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% This template is based on a template by:
% Steve Gunn (http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/srg/softwaretools/document/templates/)
% Sunil Patel (http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/)
%
% Template license:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[
12pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
%oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
english, % ngerman for German
singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
%nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
%nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Required to wrap figures around text
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font by default

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric-comp,natbib=true]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition} % Used for definitions
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
\newcommand{\change}[1]{\todo[color=green!40]{#1}}
\newcommand{\answer}[1]{\todo[color=blue!20]{#1}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGIN SETTINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
    outer=3.8cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
    top=1.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\thesistitle{CloudCache: Caching for Mobile Augmented Reality Applications} % Your thesis title, this is used in the title and abstract, print it elsewhere with \ttitle
\supervisor{Dr. Nicola \textsc{Tonelotto}} % Your supervisor's name, this is used in the title page, print it elsewhere with \supname
\examiner{} % Your examiner's name, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \examname
\degree{Master Degree} % Your degree name, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \degreename
\author{Luca \textsc{Lovagnini}} % Your name, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \authorname
\addresses{} % Your address, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \addressname

\subject{Computer Science} % Your subject area, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \subjectname
\keywords{} % Keywords for your thesis, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \keywordnames
\university{\href{https://www.di.unipi.it/en/}{University of Pisa} } % Your university's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \univname

\department{\href{http://department.university.com}{Department or School Name}} % Your department's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \deptname
\group{\href{http://researchgroup.university.com}{Research Group Name}} % Your research group's name and URL, this is used in the title page, print it elsewhere with \groupname
\faculty{\href{http://faculty.university.com}{Faculty Name}} % Your faculty's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \facname

\AtBeginDocument{
\hypersetup{pdftitle=\ttitle} % Set the PDF's title to your title
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorname} % Set the PDF's author to your name
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames} % Set the PDF's keywords to your keywords
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter % Use roman page numbering style (i, ii, iii, iv...) for the pre-content pages

\pagestyle{plain} % Default to the plain heading style until the thesis style is called for the body content

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\vspace*{.06\textheight}
{\scshape\LARGE \univname\par}\vspace{1.5cm} % University name
\textsc{\Large Master Degree Thesis}\\[0.5cm] % Thesis type

\HRule \\[0.4cm] % Horizontal line
{\huge \bfseries \ttitle\par}\vspace{0.4cm} % Thesis title
\HRule \\[1.5cm] % Horizontal line

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
\href{http://www.johnsmith.com}{\authorname} % Author name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
\href{http://www.jamessmith.com}{\supname} % Supervisor name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link  
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[3cm]

\vfill

\large \textit{A thesis submitted in fulfillment of the requirements\\ for the degree of \degreename}\\[0.3cm] % University requirement text
\textit{in the}\\[0.4cm]
\groupname\\\deptname\\[2cm] % Research group name and department name

\vfill

{\large \today}\\[4cm] % Date
%\includegraphics{Logo} % University/department logo - uncomment to place it

\vfill
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DECLARATION PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{declaration}
\addchaptertocentry{\authorshipname} % Add the declaration to the table of contents
\noindent I, \authorname, declare that this thesis titled, \enquote{\ttitle} and the work presented in it are my own. I confirm that:

\begin{itemize} 
\item This work was done wholly or mainly while in candidature for a research degree at this University.
\item Where any part of this thesis has previously been submitted for a degree or any other qualification at this University or any other institution, this has been clearly stated.
\item Where I have consulted the published work of others, this is always clearly attributed.
\item Where I have quoted from the work of others, the source is always given. With the exception of such quotations, this thesis is entirely my own work.
\item I have acknowledged all main sources of help.
\item Where the thesis is based on work done by myself jointly with others, I have made clear exactly what was done by others and what I have contributed myself.\\
\end{itemize}

\noindent Signed:\\
\rule[0.5em]{25em}{0.5pt} % This prints a line for the signature

\noindent Date:\\
\rule[0.5em]{25em}{0.5pt} % This prints a line to write the date
\end{declaration}

\cleardoublepage

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   QUOTATION PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\vspace*{0.2\textheight}

\noindent\enquote{\itshape Thanks to my solid academic training, today I can write hundreds of words on virtually any topic without possessing a shred of information, which is how I got a good job in journalism.}\bigbreak

\hfill Dave Barry

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{abstract}
\addchaptertocentry{\abstractname} % Add the abstract to the table of contents
Cloud Computing made the idea of on-demand, scalable and high available resources a low-cost reality. In the smartphone era, where devices (with limited computation and battery power) produce a massive quantity of data, Mobile Cloud Computing has become an hot topic in research community. In particular, it has been successfully exploited in the developement of many Augmented Reality (AR) applications designed for mobile devices, where local computation is too much expensive for the single smartphone. In this context, reduce the time needed for tasks computation gain advantages for both providers and end-users, giving a better user experience and saving battery life. In this paper we introduce CloudCache, a framework designed to improve performance of mobile AR applications, where previous (expensive) computations performed by the Back End system are reused in order to speedup similar tasks in the future, resulting the first memoization-like system . The design and implementation of CloudCache is described, where different tools from previous works in Computer Vision has been used to achieve the desired performance. Some of these tools has been parallelized to exploit the multi-cores architectures commonly presented in most of Cloud providers nowadays. CloudCache has been tested on three recognition Augmented Reality applications, where two new image datasets are presented to evaluate the system and the performance of the original applications has been greatly improved . \ldots
\end{abstract}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{acknowledgements}
\addchaptertocentry{\acknowledgementname} % Add the acknowledgements to the table of contents
The acknowledgments and the people to thank go here, don't forget to include your project advisor\todo{Write acknowledgements} \ldots
\end{acknowledgements}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LIST OF CONTENTS/FIGURES/TABLES PAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\tableofcontents % Prints the main table of contents

\listoftodos

\listoffigures % Prints the list of figures

\listoftables % Prints the list of tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABBREVIATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{abbreviations}{ll} % Include a list of abbreviations (a table of two columns)

\textbf{CC}     & \textbf{C}loud \textbf{C}omputing\\
\textbf{MCC}    & \textbf{M}obile \textbf{C}loud \textbf{C}omputing\\
\textbf{AR}     & \textbf{A}ugmented \textbf{R}reality\\
\textbf{MARA}   & \textbf{M}obile \textbf{A}ugmentd \textbf{R}eality \textbf{A}pplications\\
\textbf{CBIR}   & \textbf{C}ontent \textbf{B}ased \textbf{I}mage \textbf{R}etrieval\\
\textbf{IRMA}   & \textbf{I}mage \textbf{R}ecognition \textbf{M}obile \textbf{A}pplications\\
\textbf{NN}     & \textbf{N}earest \textbf{N}eighbors\\
\textbf{ANN}    & \textbf{A}pproximate \textbf{N}earest \textbf{N}eighbors\\
\textbf{BoF}    & \textbf{B}ag (of) \textbf{F}eatures\\
\textbf{VLAD}   & \textbf{V}ector (of) \textbf{L}ocally \textbf{A}ggregated \textbf{D}escriptors)\\
\textbf{FV}     & \textbf{F}isher \textbf{V}ectors\\
\textbf{GMM}    & \textbf{G}aussian \textbf{M}ixture \textbf{M}odel\\
\textbf{LRU}    & \textbf{L}east \textbf{R}ecently \textbf{U}sed\\
\textbf{SIFT}   & \textbf{S}cale \textbf{I}nvariant \textbf{F}eature \textbf{T}ransform\\
\textbf{SURF}   & \textbf{S}peeded \textbf{U}p \textrm{R}obust \textbf{F}eatures\\
\textbf{HA}     & \textbf{H}essian \textbf{A}ffine\\
\textbf{PHA}    & \textbf{P}arallel \textbf{H}essian \textbf{A}ffine\\
\textbf{ROC}    & \textbf{R}eceiver \textbf{O}perating \textbf{C}haracteristic
\end{abbreviations}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SYMBOLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{symbols}{lll} % Include a list of Symbols (a three column table)

$a$ & distance & \si{\meter} \\
$P$ & power & \si{\watt} (\si{\joule\per\second}) \\
%Symbol & Name & Unit \\

\addlinespace % Gap to separate the Roman symbols from the Greek

$\omega$ & angular frequency & \si{\radian} \\

\end{symbols}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DEDICATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\dedicatory{For/Dedicated to/To my \todo{Write something here} \ldots} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS CONTENT - CHAPTERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\mainmatter % Begin numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering

\pagestyle{thesis} % Return the page headers back to the "thesis" style

% Include the chapters of the thesis as separate files from the Chapters folder
% Uncomment the lines as you write the chapters

\include{Chapters/Introduction}
\include{Chapters/Background} 
\include{Chapters/Motivation}
\include{Chapters/Approach}
\include{Chapters/Implementation}
\include{Chapters/Evaluation}
\include{Chapters/Conclusions}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS CONTENT - APPENDICES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\appendix % Cue to tell LaTeX that the following "chapters" are Appendices

% Include the appendices of the thesis as separate files from the Appendices folder
% Uncomment the lines as you write the Appendices

\include{Appendices/AppendixA}
%\include{Appendices/AppendixB}
%\include{Appendices/AppendixC}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which library? The problem seems to occur with the bibliography.

Comment: Sorry you're right, I updated the question

Comment: Your code remains totally uncompilable: we have none of the included files, and the bibliography is missing!

Comment: It's  a 150 pages document with more than 200 entries in the `.bibl` file, how am I supposed to copy it? :D The point is that I don't understand what the error is.

Comment: Perhaps there are errors in the .bib file. Try opening it with `JabRef`, it will point to errors if any (often it's a simple comma missing between two fields). Also you can read what's in the `.blg` file.

Comment: That BibTeX error message is a bit hard to read as I had to scroll all the way to the right, but it looks like all your BibTeX errors are due to duplicate keys, i.e. there are multiple entries in your .bib file that has the key `yianilos1993data`etc. BibTeX doesn't like that. (On Overleaf, BibTeX errors are treated as warnings, so you'll still see your compilation complete and get a PDF.)

Comment: @LianTzeLim That solved the problem , thanks

Comment: Why did you choose this strange template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like all your BibTeX errors are due to duplicate keys, i.e. there are multiple entries in your `.bib` file that has the key `yianilos1993dataetc`. BibTeX doesn't like that. If you prune your `.bib` file to remove repeated entries, that should do it.

(Overleaf currently treats BibTeX errors as warnings, so you'll still see your compilation complete and get a PDF.)